# Show that a quotient function is continuous

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, continuity, quotient-spaces

Let $R_1$ and $R_2$ be equivalence relations on the spaces $X$ and $Y$, respectively. Given a continuous function $f$ such that $xR_1y$ implies $f(x)R_2f(y)$, prove that the induced function $\smash[t]{\hat{f}}: X/R_1 \to Y/R_2$, defined as $\smash[t]{\hat{f}}([x]) = [f(x)]$, is well-defined and continuous.

I am trying to prove that $\hat{f}\bigl([x]\bigr) = \bigl[f(x)\bigr]$ is continuous, so here is my attempt.

Consider the following diagram:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X @>{f}>> Y \\
@V{q_1}VV @VV{q_2}V \\
X/R_1 @>{\smash[t]{\hat{f}}}>> Y/R_2
\end{CD}

Note that $\hat{f}^{-1} = (q_2 \circ f \circ q_1^{-1})^{-1}$. We must show that $q_1(f(q_2^{-1}(V^{\text{ab}})) \subset X/R_1$, where $(V^{\text{open}}) \subseteq Y/R_2$.
We will demonstrate the continuity of $\smash[t]{\hat{f}}$. Consider the following implications:

If $(V^{\text{open}}) \subseteq Y/R_2$, it follows that $(q_2^{-1}(V^{\text{open}})) \subset Y$ due to the properties of the quotient function.

Since $f$ is a continuous function, we can conclude that $f^{-1}(q_2^{-1}(V^{\text{open}})) \subset X$.

Furthermore, as $q_{1}$ is also a quotient function, we have $q_1(f^{-1}(q_2^{-1}(V^{\text{open}}))) \subset X/R_1$.

We have shown that the preimage of any open set in $Y/R_2$ is an open set in $X/R_1$, which means that $\hat{f}$ is continuous. Therefore, we have demonstrated that $\smash[t]{\hat{f}}: X/R_1 \to Y/R_2$ is a continuous function.

Any correction or help is well received.

Comment: It seems that you are assuming that $\hat{f}$ is bijective. Otherwise, how do you know that the inverse exists?

Comment: @jjagmath "I understand, so should I start with an open set in X/R1 then? and proof that $\hat{f}([x])$ is continuous using $\hat{f}= q_{2} \circ f \circ q_{1}^{-1}$.

Comment: The function $q_1$ is bijective? How do you know that $q_1^{-1}$ exists? When you write the composition of functions like that you're assuming that the inverse exists. Note that you want the inverse **image** of a set. That always make sense even if the function is not bijective. So it's ok to take $V$ an open subset of $Y/R_2$ and consider $q_1(f^{-1}(q_2^{-1}(V)))$ but here you are taking two inverse images and then a direct image, but that in general is not the same that taking the composition of the functions and apply the direct (or inverse) image of the composition.

Comment: Also, in your arguments prove that $q_1(f^{-1}(q_2^{-1}(V^{\text{ab}})))$ is a **subset** of $X/R_1$ but why is it open?

Comment: @jjagmath In this case, I used the fact that if $f: X \to Y$ is surjective and continuous, we will say that $f$ is a quotient function if $Y$ has the quotient topology, which means $V^{\text{open}} \subset Y$ if and only if $f^{-1}(V^{\text{open}}) \subset X$. Then, using this, since $q_2$ is a quotient map, for any open set in $Y/R_2, q_{1}^{-1}(V^{\text{open}}) \subset Y$ is open. Since $f$ is continuous, it maps open sets to open sets, so $f^{-1}(q_{2}^{-1}(V^{\text{ab}})) \subset X$. Using the argument I provided earlier, $q_{1}(f^{-1}(q_{2}^{-1}(V^{\text{ab}}))) \subset X/R_{1}$

Comment: " We must show that $q_1(f(q_2^{-1}(V^{\text{ab}})) \subset X/R_1$, where $(V^{\text{ab}}) \subseteq Y/R_2$."  What does $V^{ab}$ mean? Is it an open or a closed set? And isn't $q_1(f(q_2^{-1}(V^{\text{ab}})) \subset X/R_1$ trivial?  You don't claim that it is open or closed.

Comment: "Since $f$ is continuous, it maps open sets to open sets, ..." This is wrong. Since $f$ is continuous, the inverse image of an open set is open.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $q_{2}: Y \rightarrow Y/R_{2}$ given by $q_{2}: y \mapsto [y]$, which is the definition of the quotient function. Let $U^{\text{open}}\subseteq Y/R_{2}$, then $(q_{2}^{-1}(U))^{\text{ab}}\subseteq Y$, this is by the definition of the quotient function, and since $f$ is continuous, we have
$$\left(f^{-1}\left(q_{2}^{-1}(U)\right)\right)^{\text{ab}}\subseteq X$$

Note also that
$$f^{-1}\left(q_{2}^{-1}(U)\right)=\left((q_{2} \circ f)^{-1}(U) \right)^{\text{open}}\subseteq X$$

So $(q_{2} \circ f)$ is continuous.

Furthermore, note that as $\hat{f} \circ q_{1} = q_{2} \circ f$, then $\hat{f} \circ q_{1}$ is continuous, where $q_{1}: X \rightarrow X/R_{1}$ is the canonical map induced by the equivalence relation $R_{1}$; hence,
$$\hat{f} \text{is continuous}$$

Answer (score 1):

> A map from a quotient space $X/R$ to another topological space is continuous if and only if the composition with the quotient map $q:  X\to X/R$ is continuous.

Because $q_2\circ f$ is  continuous, your $\hat f$ is continuous.